# Reusing dynamic sql fragments

Tags: mybatis

Hei there, I'm working on a Primefaces app and as a persistence layer I chose [Mybatis](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/).

This is how a regular sql would look in my mapper:

```
<select id="getAllTransportUnit" resultMap="TransportUnitMap">
    SELECT * FROM SSLS_GUI.VW_TU
    <if test="( hasFilters == 'yes' ) and ( parameters != null )">
        <where>
            <foreach item="clause" collection="parameters" separator=" AND "
                open="(" close=")">
                UPPER(${clause.column}) ${clause.operator} #{clause.value}
            </foreach>
        </where>
    </if>
    <if test="sort == 'true'">
        ORDER BY ${sortField}
        <if test="sortOrder == 'DESC'"> DESC</if>
        <if test="sortOder == 'ASC'"> ASC</if>
    </if>
</select>
```

Almost all my queries use the dynamic sql part starting from the `<if test...>`. Is it possible to put it in a separate file and then reuse it all over my queries?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several options how to reuse sql snippets.

### SQL snippets and include

The first one is using `include`. Create separate mapper Common.xml:

```
<mapper namespace="com.company.project.common">
    <sql id="orderBy>
      <if test="sort == 'true'">
        ORDER BY ${sortField}
        <if test="sortOrder == 'DESC'"> DESC</if>
        <if test="sortOder == 'ASC'"> ASC</if>
      </if>
    </sql>
    

    <sql id="filters">
     <if test="( hasFilters == 'yes' ) and ( parameters != null )">
      <where>
        <foreach item="clause" collection="parameters" separator=" AND "
            open="(" close=")">
            UPPER(${clause.column}) ${clause.operator} #{clause.value}
        </foreach>
     </where>
    </if>
  </sql>
</mapper>
```

And the use it in other mappers `MyMapper.xml`:

```
<select id="getAllTransportUnit" resultMap="TransportUnitMap">
  SELECT * FROM SSLS_GUI.VW_TU
  <include refid="com.company.project.common.filters"/>
  <include refid="com.company.project.common.orderBy"/>
</select>
```

To avoid duplicating namespace in every include you can create shortcut snippets in `MyMapper.xml`:

```
<sql id="orderBy">
  <include refid="com.company.project.common.orderBy"/> 
</sql>

<select id="getAllTransportUnit" resultMap="TransportUnitMap">
  SELECT * FROM SSLS_GUI.VW_TU
  <include refid="orderBy"/>
</select>
```

### Mybatis-velocity macro

Another possible option is to use mybatis [scripting](https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Scripting). Using [mybatis-velocity](http://mybatis.org/velocity-scripting/) scripting engine you can define velocity macro and use it like this.

In `Commons.xml`:

```
<sql id="macros"
  #macro(filters)
    #if ( $_parameter.hasFilters )
      #repeat( $_parameter.parameters $clause "AND" " (" ")" )
        ${clause.column} ${clause.operator} @{clause.value}
      #end
    #end
  #end
  
  #macro(order_by)
  .. 
  #end
</sql>
```

In `MyMapper.xml`:

```
<select id="getAllTransportUnit" resultMap="TransportUnitMap">
  <include refid="macros"/>
  SELECT * FROM SSLS_GUI.VW_TU
  #filters()
  #order_by()
</select>
```

Including macros via sql snippet is not the most clean way to reuse macros. It is just an idea how this is used.

Much better option is to configure mybatis-velocity and specify what global macros are available. In this case there will be no need to  include `macros` snippet and result query will be like this:

```
<select id="getAllTransportUnit" resultMap="TransportUnitMap">
  SELECT * FROM SSLS_GUI.VW_TU
  #filters()
  #order_by()
</select>
```

Comment: I was not aware that `include` was a thing in *Mybatis*. This is good to know.

Answer (score 1):

See @Roman Konoval's answer for how to do this in XML.

For another option on the pure Java side (in OP's case, the XML option above is more applicable; I leave this here for those who may be using pure Java), one can use Mybatis' [Statement Builders](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html), which allow for the construction of dynamic *SQL* inline with *Java* code, you can factor out the common code there similar to the way you would factor out any common code.

The example they give in the *Mybatis* doc is as follows:

```
private String selectPersonSql() {
  return new SQL() {{
    SELECT("P.ID, P.USERNAME, P.PASSWORD, P.FULL_NAME");
    SELECT("P.LAST_NAME, P.CREATED_ON, P.UPDATED_ON");
    FROM("PERSON P");
    FROM("ACCOUNT A");
    INNER_JOIN("DEPARTMENT D on D.ID = P.DEPARTMENT_ID");
    INNER_JOIN("COMPANY C on D.COMPANY_ID = C.ID");
    WHERE("P.ID = A.ID");
    WHERE("P.FIRST_NAME like ?");
    OR();
    WHERE("P.LAST_NAME like ?");
    GROUP_BY("P.ID");
    HAVING("P.LAST_NAME like ?");
    OR();
    HAVING("P.FIRST_NAME like ?");
    ORDER_BY("P.ID");
    ORDER_BY("P.FULL_NAME");
  }}.toString();
}
```

So, you could define a function that factors out your commmon dynamic *SQL* from your XML, and perhaps takes arguments representing the `SELECT` columns and `FROM` table portions of the statement (and anything else that might vary), which can then be passed in to the factored-out dynamic *SQL* methods inside of the function.