# How can i reuse an <insert> tag in mybatis?

Tags: sql, xml, include, mybatis

I am inserting object A in database with parameter (A a). The object like that

```
A {
   List<B> b;
   List<C> c;
}
```

In mapper file I use this function:

```
void register(@Param("a")A a);
```

In mapper.xml, I wrote the following code:

```
<insert id="registerB" parameterType="java.util.List">
    <foreach>...</foreach>
</insert>

<insert id="registerC" parameterType="java.util.List">
    <foreach>...</foreach>
</insert>

<insert id="register">
//TODO include insert registerB and registerC
</insert>
```

How can i include the inserting of list of B and C into insert query of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse insert sql snippets easily in the `mapper.xml`. The problem is not with sql strings themselves this can be done (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055276/reusing-dynamic-sql-fragments/25073775#25073775) for example).

The problem will be with referencing parameters. In insert for `registerB` for example the parameter is a list of `B`s. And you can't redefine it to use them easily from `register`.

You can however use java8 default methods to reuse `registerB` and `registerC` from java code like this:

```
interface MyMapper {
   void registerB(@Param("b")B b);

   void registerC(@Param("c")C c);

   default void register(@Param("a")A a) {
       registerB(a.getB());
       registerC(a.getC());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In Xml file it can not include <insert> tag, so we can write it in mapper interface class :)))